# Generating undirected network with pre-specified degree distribution without any self loops

Tags: r

I would like to generate an undirected network with 100 nodes, where half of the nodes have a degree of 10 and the other half has a degree of 3. Is such a network possible to construct without self loops?

Using the code specified below:

```
library(graph)
degrees=c(rep(3,50),rep(10,50))
names(degrees)=paste("node",seq_along(degrees)) #nodes must be names
x=randomNodeGraph(degrees)
```

I can obtain such a graph, but there are self-loops included.

Is there any way to get a graph without self loops?

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to do with the graph package from Bioconductor ([see here](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/graph.html))

```
#install graph from Bioconductor
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("graph")

#load graph and make the specified graph
library(graph)
degrees=c(rep(3,50),rep(10,50))
names(degrees)=paste("node",seq_along(degrees)) #nodes must be names
x=randomNodeGraph(degrees)

#verify graph
edges=edgeMatrix(x)
edgecount=table(as.vector(edges))
table(edgecount)
#edgecount
# 3 10 
#50 50
```

Comment: is it also possible to represent this graph in a 2 column format instead of an adjacency matrix?

Comment: Does `t(edges)` get you what you want?

Comment: so the graph that you proposed is directed, the total degree is composed of in and outdegree. I would like to have a graph where if node 1 is connected to node 5 then the same connection holds from node 5 to node 1. is this possible to do?

Comment: the randomNodeGraph help says that: Self-loops are allowed. The resultant graph is directed (but can always be coerced to be undirected). but I cannot find how to coerce it to be undirected. can you help with this?

Comment: `ugraph(x)` is the underlying undirected graph

Comment: thanks this is really helpful. unfortunately when I make it undirected the degree distribution is broken. can I somehow preserve the degree?

Comment: I think it might just be breaking because it's not counting self-loops twice, but i'm not sure

Comment: can I disable self loops somehow?

Comment: the documentation doesnt say anything about how to disable self-loops

Comment: I started a bounty and would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The [Erdős–Gallai theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem) answers the question *if* such a graph is possible to construct.

[image]

It is based on the non-decreasing degree sequence of your graph which is in your case

```
ds <- c( rep( 10, 50 ), rep(3,50) )
```

You can calculate the right-hand side of the inequality by

```
rhs <- (1:100 * 0:99) + c( rev(cumsum(rev(apply( data.frame(ds, 1:100) , 1, min ))))[-1], 0 )
```

And the left-hand side by

```
lhs <- cumsum( ds )
```

Finally:

```
all( lhs <= rhs )
[1] TRUE
```